# input_shape 2D Convolutional layer in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras

In the Keras Documentation for `Convolution2D` the `input_shape` a 128x128 RGB pictures is given by `input_shape=(3, 128, 128)`, thus I figured the first component should be the number of planes (or feature layers).

If I run the following code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(4, 5,5, border_mode='same', input_shape=(3, 19, 19), activation='relu'))
print(model.output_shape)
```

I get an `output_shape`of `(None, 3, 19, 4)`, whereas in my understanding this should be `(None, 4, 19, 19)` with 4 the number of filters.

Is this an error in the example from the keras documentation or am I missing something?

(I am trying to recreate a part of AlphaGo so the 19x19 is the board size which would correspond to the images size. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the Theano dimension ordering  `(channels, rows, cols)` as input but your Keras seems to use the Tensorflow one which is `(rows, cols, channels)`.

So either you can switch to the Theano dimension ordering, directly in your code with :

`import keras.backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')`

Or editing the `keras.json` file in (usually in `~\.keras`) and switching

`"image_dim_ordering": "tf"` to `"image_dim_ordering": "th"`

Or you can keep the Tensorflow dimension ordering and switch your `input_shape` to `(19,19,3)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be (None, 4, 19, 19). There is something called `dim_ordering` in keras that decides in which index should one place the `number of input channels`. Check the documentation of "dim_ordering" parameter in the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#convolution2d). Mine is set to 'tf'.

So; just change the `input shape` to `(19, 19, 3)` like so

`model.add(Convolution2D(4, 5,5, border_mode='same', input_shape=(19, 19,3), activation='relu'))`

Then check the output shape.

You can also modify the `dim_ordering` in the file usually at `~/.keras/keras.json` to your liking